# Understanding the rotation of a photograph of an object due to relativistic effects

Tags: special-relativity

I came across an interesting question in the Hartle's textbook, "An Introduction to Eisntein's General Relativity". The question is as follows:

*Explain why a photograph of an object moving uniformly with a speed approaching the speed of light, parallel to the plane of the film appears not contracted, but rather, rotated. (Assume that the object subtends a small angle from the camera lens.)*

Hartle argues that if we consider a rectangular object moving parallel to the plane of the film with speed $V$, whose length is of rest length $a$ and breadth of rest length $b$, then the effect can be attributed to the fact that light coming from the far side takes a longer time of $b/c$ than the short side to get to the film.

My question is, what exactly does does Hartle meant by far and near side? And, why does light need to travel an extra distance $b$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation

Comment: But why does light need to travel an extra distance $b$? It is not clear to me why this specific distance is the extra distance.

Comment: A full derivation can be found [here](https://www.andrewyork.net/Math/TerrellRotation_York.html).